PaddleOCR misclassify table as figure
I try to Extract Table from image using PaddleOcr and when i give it a scanned documment image that contain table the model PaddleDetectionLayoutModel classify it as figure and when I turn PDFs converted to images the model work fine
This the code i Used
import cv2
import layoutparser as lp

image = cv2.imread('/content/images/mc.png')
image = image[...,::-1]

#load model
model = lp.PaddleDetectionLayoutModel(config_path =         "lp://PubLayNet/ppyolov2_r50vd_dcn_365e_publaynet/config",
                                     threshold = 0.2,
                                     label_map = {0: "Text", 1: "Title", 2: "List", 3:"Table",       4:"Figure"},
                                     enforce_cpu=True,
                                     enable_mkldnn = True)

# detect
layout = model.detect(image)

This is the image I used
enter image description here
And this is the Output:
Layout(_blocks=[TextBlock(block=Rectangle(x_1=10.520721435546875, y_1=4.0593109130859375, x_2=477.2168273925781, y_2=338.47991943359375), text=None, id=None, type=Figure, parent=None, next=None, score=0.9354115724563599)], page_data={})
